# Книга о том как писать компиляторы на языке C/C++

Tags: c++, c, книги

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошую книгу, на русском языке о том, как написать компилятор на языках С/С++. И ещё книгу или хорошую статью 
"как писать парсеры математических выражений".
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А статьи поищите на хабре

Comment: Я там нашел лишь на F#, а в программировании я еще можно сказать NULL, и не пойму как реализовать на С/С++

Comment: >>Книга о том как писать компиляторы на языке C/C++

и

>>в программировании я еще можно сказать NULL

Может стоит начать с изучения алгоритмов (к примеру на паскале), потом с учебника по C/C++, а потом уже переходить к компиляторам?

Comment: Не думаю, я уже прочел 
Лафоре ООП С++
Веревка достаточной длины чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу
Липман С++ Для начинающих
так что, думаю с этим я справлюсь)

Comment: @Artemiy_plus_plus, если вкратце, но конкретно, и писать собираетесь на С++, то используйте рекурсивный разбор компилируемого языка (если, конечно, грамматика языка позволяет).

Для разбора выражений с последующей генерацией кода или их интерпретацией отлично подходят стеки операций с их приоритетами и операндов.

По ходу дела строите таблицу символов с указанием типа операнда.

Comment: @Artemiy_plus_plus, никогда ещё вы так не ошибались :)

Comment: @Construct  в чём я ошибся так сильно? :)

Comment: Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation (c) Shriram Krishnamurthi https://cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/ , перевод с дополнениями по flex/bison/c++ в процессе https://github.com/ponyatov/PLAI/releases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для написания парсеров на C умудрённые опытом домохозяйки используют lex/yacc. По нему много литературы, например, [O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do).

Для написания полновесного компилятора читайте [Dragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design) [Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3A_Principles%2C_Techniques%2C_and_Tools). Не жалуйтесь, что книги сложные.

Comment: Я и не жалуюсь, я понимаю что ничего простого нет)
Спасибо.)

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Перед чтением книг в стиле "книга дракона", я бы рекомендовал просмотреть очень занимательное введение в разработку компиляторов - [Джек Креншоу. Давайте создадим компилятор!](ftp://po.istu.ru/public/docs/other/_New/Documantation/Compilat/crenshaw/crenshaw.html).

Хотя там используют старый диалект паскаля, но от этого книга не стает хуже. Но вот базисные вещи научит писать. После ее прочтения и анализа простенький скриптовый язык или компилятор (хотя я бы назвал транслятором то, что получиться, так как скорее всего научитесь писать программу, которая переведет код с Вашего языка в С или ассемблер) будет уже не так сложно.

Comment: У меня есть книга Крешноу Д., но что то я побоялся ее читать, раз на паскале.

Answer (score 4):

Если вести речь вообще о внутреннем устройстве и  разработке языков, то [Языки программирования: разработка и реализация](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1158230)  Т. Пратт, М. Зелковиц безусловно стоит почитать.

Я читал когда-то первое издание, а вот современное (4-е) с кучей новых языков, к сожалению, как-то в продаже не попадается.

**Update**

Вот чуть погуглил и с 3-ей примерно страницы качнул его (4-е на русском, правда, djvu (в транспорте на моих девайсах не почитаешь...)).

Comment: Хорошо) добавлю к спискам литературы)

Answer (score 3):

Вот ещё неплохая книга: [Языки программирования и методы трансляции](http://progbook.ru/technologiya-programmirovaniya/798-sverdlov-yazyki-programmirovaniya-i-metody.html)

Comment: Врятли я смогу понять, там ведь C#, Java и Оберон, но всеравно спасибо, я попробую :)

Comment: Описание на сайте скопипасчено не пойми откуда, в книге примеры кода в основном на паскале, переписать на C труда не должно составить) Главное принципы понять...

Answer (score 2):

[Книга Дракона](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3829076/)